# Drag and drop event sometimes doesnt execute the DOM

Tags: javascript, html

I have a textarea that has the id = `display`

javascript:

```
<script>
function drag(event) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text", this.event.target.src);
}
function drop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let data = event.dataTransfer.files;
    for (file of data) {
        var l = document.getElementById('display').selectionStart;
        var text = document.getElementById("display").value;
        sub1 = text.substring(l,0);
        var len = text.length;
        var l2 = sub1.length;
        sub2 = text.substring(len,l2);
        var test = sub1 + file.name + sub2;
        var end = document.getElementById("display").textContent = test;
        alert(end);
    }
}
function allow(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
</script>
```

I type in some text and want to put the dragged file in between the text. When i run this code, the alert shows the correct content, but the DOM never updates.

This only occurs when i input text in the area myself. For example if text is already in the field and i drag and drop the DOM wont update even though the alert shows the correct content.

I have spent countless hours trying to debug this but cant seem to find a solution.

The demo below you will see if you type in the textarea it doesnt work with the drag and drop. But if you dont press any keys and just keep on dragging images it will work

[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/esjd1c7r/3/)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
var end = document.getElementById("display").textContent = test;
```

Should be:

```
var end = document.getElementById("display").value = test;
```

.textContent is replaced with .value